# Comparing time in Excel

Tags: excel, time

I just take a look on some question but none of them worked for me.
I have an Excel sheet where I need to control some systems SLA, so I have columns like follow:

10:20 AM(COLUMN C)  13:00 EST(COLUMN D) 1:00 PM(COLUMN E)
On column E, I have the follow formula: **=TEXT(LEFT(D1630;5);"H:MM AM/PM")** and finally on Column F I have the following: =IF(ISBLANK(C1630);"";IF(TEXT(C1630;"H:MM AM/PM")<=E1630;"Met";"Missed"))

However the formula doesn't work, sometimes show as "Met", sometime as "Missed".
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand everything, but you should probably be comparing times and not strings.  Try the following formulas (and adapt them to your desired row and also replace the commas with semicolons)

```
E1:  =TIMEVALUE(LEFT(D1,5))
F1:  =IF(C1<=E1,"Met","Missed")
```

You should probably format E1 as `h:mm am/pm` but that is not necessary for the formula to work.